# Why I always get 2.8284 when estimating Pi using PRNGs?

Tags: c++, random, pi, estimation

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to statistically determine the value of Pi based on Ernesto Cesaro's Theorem using the computer system's random number generator. But what I have done now can input a seed number and generate 100 pseudo random numbers and then estimate the value of pi. The generator can generate different group of Pseudo random numbers. However the confusion is I always get the estimate of pi for 2.8284 with no change. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int seed;
   cout << "input a seed number: " << endl;
   cin >> seed;
   srand(seed);
   int i, a[100];
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      a[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
      cout << "The generated random numbers are: " << endl;
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      cout << a[i] << "\t";
   int m, n, j, r;
   int  sum = 0;
   for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
   {
      m = a[j];
      n = a[j + 1];
      j = j + 2;
      do
      {
          r = m%n;
          m = n;
          n = r;
      } while (r != 0);
        if (n = 1)
        sum = sum + 1;
   }
   double Pi, p;
   p = 300 / sum;
   Pi = sqrt(p);
   cout << "The estimate value of Pi is: " << Pi << endl;
   system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Note that Cesaro's theorem states that given two random integers, x and y, the probability that gcd(x, y) = 1 is 6/(Pi^2). And PRNG used affects how close the resulting estimate is to Pi(3.1416).

Comment: Why are you modifying the loop counter *inside the loop*?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth j=j+2?

Comment: Where's the magic number 300 coming from?  You're doing 100 trials, so `sum / 100 == 6 / Pi^2` ==> `Pi == sqrt(6 * 100 / sum)` should be your estimator (after making sure you do floating point arithmetic).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yeah! I should delete that. Thx!

Comment: Why are you only generating integers that are 1 to 100, and worse, doing so using modulo arithmetic?  `rand` is already a crappy generator with bad serial correlation problems in the low bits, and using `%` introduces modulo bias on top of that.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  I should delete inside j increment and add j += 2 in the for line. Thank you!

Comment: @pjs: the modulo bias here will be tiny (assuming 32-bit RAND_MAX), orders of magnitude smaller than the errors due to the actual bugs in this code...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, but once the bugs are cleaned up it will affect the outcome.  It can have a disproportionate effect since the count ends up in the denominator of the estimator.

Comment: @pjs: the relative error is < 1/20e6, getting close to ULP for single precision....

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'd be interested in how you're calculating that, given that the error in this case is determined by shifting the relative likelihoods of two values which are checked for relative primality, a very non-linear operation.

Comment: @pjs According to rand, what you think should be a good generator with functional capability to generate PRNs?

Comment: I think the answer probably lies in reflecting on exactly what the P in "PRNG" stands for.

Comment: @HaonanYang Since you're using C++, why not go for `std::mt19937`?

Comment: @pjs: My premise is that the result will be skewed by what proportion of the sub-results (i.e. "co-prime or not?") are "wrong", in the sense of being due to over-representation of input values.  That proportion is (100/RAND_MAX) here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I implemented the algorithm, ran it with a million observations per trial, replicated 20 times, and calculated confidence intervals.  When I used raw mt19937_64 outcomes, the resulting CI was [3.1415432457256016, 3.1426083921503554], i.e, contains the true value of Pi.  When I did the same using modulo 100 values, the resulting CI was [3.1594316865330003, 3.160795226099586], i.e., does not contain the true value of Pi.  In fact, the estimate was 54.3 standard errors from the true answer.  Using modulo 100 introduces a statistically significant amount of bias.

Comment: @pjs: To double-check, in the first case, are you still forcing a random range [1,100] (rather than [1,RAND_MAX])?  If so, then wow, I'll need to think about the discrepancy between my hand-wavy assumptions and the empirical evidence!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, I wasn't forcing a range of [1,100].  I was using the raw integer output.  When I use `1 + rand(100)` (I did this in Ruby, which uses mt19937 as its builtin PRNG) the results came in at about 10 standard errors below the true value of Pi.  It looks like the best way to get unbiased estimates is to not artificially constrain the ranges for the integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

**Issue #1:**

```
if (n = 1)
```

It should be `if (n == 1)` or else you are assigning `1` to `n` and always evaluating to true.

**Issue #2:**

```
      n = r;
  } while (r != 0);
  if (n == 1)
```

If you think about it, the loop will end only when `r` is `0`, but then `n` will also be `0` because of the last line of the loop. So `n` will never be equal to `1`. You probably want `if (m == 1)`.

**Issue #3:**

```
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    ...
    j = j + 2;
```

You are incrementing the `j` in the `for` line and in the loop body. You just need one.

```
for (j = 0; j < 100; j += 2)
{
    //no j increment
```

**Issue #4:**

```
p = 300 / sum;
```

That is an integer division, because both numbers are integers. You want foating point: `p = 300.0 / sum;`.

With those changes I'm getting about `3.16`.

Comment: I've been trying several different seeds. Why were there exist fluctuating values in the results of the range from about 2.9 to 3.6? Why it can not being clustered in a small range around 3.14 (such as 3.1 to 3.2)?

Comment: @HaonanYang Because 100 is a very small sample size for estimating proportions.  Try it with 10k, 100k, or even a million.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in the algorithm. (not four :p )

First - the numbers are coprime when gcd is not greater than 1, also you should check `m` value not `n` (see rodrigo's answer). So you need to change if to this:

```
if (m <= 1)
    sum = sum + 1; // ++sum;
```

Second error is your estimator: `p = 300 / sum;`.  Why do you use 300?  The correct one is:

```
float pi = sqrt ( 6.f * iterations / sum) // from p = 6 / pi^2
```

where `iterations` in your code is 34 (because you change `j`-index in the loop body).

Comment: Thank you! What's the "iterations" stands for?

Comment: 300 is simply `(100 / 2) * 6` being 100 the counter of random numbers, 2 because they are treated on pairs, 6 from the PI formula.

Comment: How can the GCD of anything be 0? 0 is not a divisior of any positive number. And certainly `m` will never be 0 at the end of the loop.

Comment: True, my mistake. Gcd(0,0) is from definition 0, but its not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've got the wrong shape. Instead of the ratio of the circumference of a circle to it's diameter (pi), you successfully estimated the ratio of the circumference of a square to it's diagonal.

i.e. a square with side 1 has a circumference of 4 and it's diagonal would be:

> sqrt(1^2+1^2) = sqrt(2)

The ratio of circumference to diagonal would therefore be:

> 4:sqrt(2) = 2.8284

Just change the square to a circle and you should be right.